function is able to parse PathValue when called by server, but not when called by test
I am able to get the PathValue from an http.Request when I run a server, but not when I run a test.
Here is my handler func
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("GET /customers/{id}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        s.Logger.Log(r.Context(), domain.INFO, "GET", r.URL.Path)

        idAsStr := r.PathValue("id")
        idAsInt, err := strconv.Atoi(idAsStr)
        if err != nil {
            errClient := domain.ErrClient{Msg: fmt.Sprintf("unable to parse customer id - %v", idAsStr)}
            s.handleBadRequest(w, r, errors.Join(errClient, err))

Here is my test
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/customers/10006.json", nil)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    h, _ := mux.Handler(req)
    h.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
    assert.Equal(t, 400, rr.Result().StatusCode)
    var msg string
    json.NewDecoder(rr.Body).Decode(&msg)
    assert.Equal(t, "unable to parse customer id - 10006.json", msg)

When I call the handler from a web browser I get
2024/04/03 11:26:50 INFO [GET /customers/10006.json]
2024/04/03 11:26:50 ERROR [client error: unable to parse customer id - 10006.json
strconv.Atoi: parsing "10006.json": invalid syntax]

When I call the handler from inside a test I get
2024/04/03 11:31:10 INFO [GET /customers/10006.json]
2024/04/03 11:36:39 ERROR [client error: unable to parse customer id - 
strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax]

Does anyone know why I am unable to parse the PathValue when called from the test?

The path value is set by mux.ServeHTTP. Then Handler.ServeHTTP is called.
func (mux *ServeMux) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    ...

        h, _, r.pat, r.matches = mux.findHandler(r)
    }
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)

The ServeHTTP function created by HandleFunc just calls the function. It doesn't do anything else.
// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}

The fixed test, using mux.ServeHTTP, instead of Handler.ServeHTTP, is below.
    mux := buildMux(t)
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "http://example.com/customers/10006.json", nil)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    mux.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
    assert.Equal(t, 400, rr.Result().StatusCode)
    var msg string
    json.NewDecoder(rr.Body).Decode(&msg)
    assert.Equal(t, "unable to parse customer id - 10006.json", msg)

